# How to pause and resume a simple snake game written in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple snake game in **JavaScript**, and

> I want to add a feature where the game can be paused and resumed when
>   a certain image is clicked,

and I am having trouble with how the function should be.

**this is the function that I wanna add, still empty though:**

```
function gamepaused(){

}
function gameResume(){

}
const pause = document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', gamePaused)
const resume = document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', gameResume)
```

and this is the inside of my gameLoop function that shows how the snake moves:

```
function gameLoop(){

position.x += movement.x
position.y += movement.y

//if snake eats the snack
if (snack.x == position.x && snack.y == position.y) {
    snake.push({...position})
    position.x += movement.x
    position.y += movement.y
    drawSnack()
    score ++
}

//if head bump with body
if (movement.x || movement.y) {
    for (let body of snake) {
        if( body.x == position.x && body.y == position.y){
            return init()
        }
    }
    //this is what makes the snake moves forward
    snake.push({...position})
    snake.shift()

  }

  drawScore(score)



 // if head hits the wall, still in game.

  if (position.x < 0 ){
      position.x = TILE
  }
  else if (position.y < 0){
      position.y = TILE
  }
  else if (position.x > TILE)  {
      position.x = -1
  }
  else if (position.y > TILE){
      position.y = -1
  }


}
setInterval (function (){
    requestAnimationFrame (gameLoop)
}, INTERVAL)
```

and you can click [here](https://github.com/felishaww/ORAI) to see the github repo for this game, if you need to look at the full code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hold you setInterval value in variable and call clearInterval to pause.
like:

`let interval`

```
interval = setInterval (function (){
    requestAnimationFrame (gameLoop)
}, INTERVAL)
```

And add code to your pause and resume function.

```
function gamepaused(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function gameResume(){
   interval = setInterval (function (){
        requestAnimationFrame (gameLoop)
    }, INTERVAL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When someone presses the pause button check set a value of a var to paused (true/false) 
Then in the game loop check if the game is paused and stop setting the interval. 
When the resume is clicked then you can set the interval again (without the delay) and of course set the paused var to false.

Another way of doing is just having the var paused like before and putting all the game loop code except the interval in an if statement that checks if the var is true or false (paused or not)